# Databricks get JSON without schema

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

What's the typical approach for getting JSON from REST API using databricks?
It returns nested structure, which can change over time and doesn't have any schema:

```
{ "page": "1",
  "total": "10",
  "payload": [
     { "param1": "value1",
       "param2": "value2"
     },
     { "param2": "value2",
       "param3": "value3"
     }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to put it into dataframe.

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: I don't load the data, it's external third-party REST API

Comment: If the volume is large enough to justify a batch, then I would fetch the data in the driver program, save it to a disk or on the network, such as in hdfs; and then create RDDs/dataframes off that local data. If the chunks are too small, then it's tricky, and I'd rather have the direction reversed so that one can use spark streaming (or, alternatively, create a light REST client that retrieves the data and stores it locally so that the spark application can take it from there)

Comment: I get this part, but how would you do the actual conversion JSON -> RDD without schema?

Comment: That all depends on your logic. If you really don't have any stable schema, then use flexible data structures, such as `Map`s. It may take some pre-processing or data cleanup before you get to a point where you can generate a data frame from your rdd.